# Get count number from mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm creating questions and answers web site using mango and express.So there are two schema for Question and Answer.

My Question and Answer Schema like this,

```
const questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
user: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
title: {type: String , required:true},
question: {type: String , required:true},
tags: {type: Array , required: true},
time : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
vote: {type: Number, default: 0},
views: {type: Number, default: 0}     });


const answerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
user: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
question:{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question', required: true},
comment: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment', default: null }],
answer: {type: String, required: true},
vote: {type: Number , default: 0},
time : { type : Date, default: Date.now }   });
```

In here there are many answers related to the one question.My home page get the all questions to preview.How to get the count number of answers related to the each question?

Comment: Do you wanted to query `question` collection with a question name & get all answers count ?

Comment: yeah.I want to get question and  answers count of each questions

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: yes,But count always get 0. I think problem in localField and foreignField names related to my schema.

Comment: ok localField is ‘_id’, I’ll update the answer..

Comment: thank you @whoami .It's work after I change from="Answer" to from="answers". It's works. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `questionSchema` doesn't have any direct relation with `Answers` collection (like doesn't store `Answers` reference) then try this :

**Query :**

```
db.Question.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "Answer",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "question",
            as: "answers"
        }
    }, 
    /** In case if you need all details of question replace 'project' with 'addFields' & remove 'question: 1' */
    { $project: { question: 1, count: { $size: '$answers' } } } 
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9aEmYwMWjq_)